# Regex - Is it neccessary to use ^ & $ in regex string for matches()?

Tags: java, regex

```
String regex1 = "^dog$";
String regex2 = "dog";
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex1);
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(regex2);
Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher("dog");
Matcher matcher2 = pattern1.matcher("doggie");
Matcher matcher3 = pattern2.matcher("dog");
Matcher matcher4 = pattern2.matcher("doggie");
System.out.println(matcher1.matches());
System.out.println(matcher2.matches());
System.out.println(matcher3.matches());
System.out.println(matcher4.matches());
```

Output:

```
true

false

true

false
```

Comment: You already know the answer, as your listing here demonstrates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you refer to [the javadoc of `Matcher:matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) :

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

So indeed, using `^` and `$` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The first and second regex should be exactly the same:

```
String regex1 = "^dog$";
```

means a string dog between start (^) and end ($)

```
String regex2 = "dog";
```

means the same things.
If you want to match `doggie` then use some wildcard like `?` or `*` or `g+`, etc...